# Posting JSON data from a Chrome browser extension to an MVC controller

Tags: json, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, google-chrome-extension

I've written a Chrome browser extension that uses Ajax to post data to an MVC3 controller.  To make sure that the controller code works, I first wrote a Razor web page to prototype the ajax code.  This code works within the web page, JSON model binding an all.  I published it to an IIS7 server complete with DNS host and domain name.  The code still works on the test page.

```
function addUrl()
{
$('#res').html('Adding...');
var myData = { url: $('#urlDiv').html(), comments: $('#c1').val() };

$.ajax(
        {
        url: 'http://hostname.domainname/ControllerName/AddUrl',
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        data:JSON.stringify(myData),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (result) 
            {
            $('#res').html(result);
            },
        error: function()
            {
            $('#res').html('An error occurred');
            }
        }
    );  
};
```

I copied this jQuery function into the Chrome JavaScript file and called it from a pop-up window via a conventional form button.

```
  <body onload="buildPopupDom();">
<form>
<h2>Add URL</h2>
<div id='urlDiv'></div>
<p>Comments<br /><textarea id="c1" cols="80" rows="3"></textarea></p>
<p><input type="button" value="Save" id="s1" onclick="addUrl();" /> <input type="button" value="Close" onclick="javascript:window.close();" /></p>
</form>
```

For some reason posts from the Chrome extension incur a 404 error and it occurred to me that that some MVC3 XSS protection or similar is blocking the post - or perhaps something in IIS7 (UrlScan is not installed).

Comment: have you declared domain permissions in the manifest?

Comment: That was the answer! For anyone else following this thread, the reference is here: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/xhr.html

Comment: Serg: if you put this question as an answer, I can give it the credit it is due.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to make cross domain XHR calls corresponding [domain permissions](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr.html) need to be declared in the manifest.

Comment: To make a cross-origin XMLHttpRequest, you have to include the target domain (see reference above).