# Sending data over chrome extension to REST

Tags: javascript, rest, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to send my selection to a server using post and server need REST, Tested my data with Advanced Rest Client and all works well, But when I try from my chrome extension I am getting undefinded error. Here is what I am trying

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
            method: 'POST',
            action: 'REST',
            headers: {'Remote-User':'myuser'},
            url: 'http://myserver/data/add/',
            data: {'content': 'the paste content'}
        }, function(responseText) {
            alert(responseText);
        });
```

Any help much appreciated, thanks

**Update**

Based sdc, I changed my code like this and still responseText is undefined :(

```
function genericOnClick(info, tab) 
{
    var url = 'http://mysite/data/add/';
    var data = $.toJSON({'content': 'the paste content'});
    $.ajax({
      headers: {
        'Remote-User':'username',
        'Content-Type':'application/json;charset=utf-8'
      },
      url: url,
      data: data,
      method: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      error:  function(xhr, status, error){
        alert(xhr.responseText);
      },
      success: function(data){
        console.log('succes: '+data);
      }

    });
}
```

Comment: can you post your Exception

Comment: I am not seeing any exception, just only "Undefined"

Comment: are you triggering your `genericOnClick` method anywhere?

Comment: I was a total idiot, I didn't add the permission on manifest.. but yeah now all works , thanks a lot sdc

Comment: Glad I could help, sorry I didn't ask about that sooner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you misunderstand the purpose of `chrome.runtime.sendMessage`. See the first two paragraphs of the [Message Passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) documentation. `sendMessage` is used for *"communication between extensions and their [content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)"* it is not designed for sending an HTTP request.

A content script must also *"set up a runtime.onMessage event listener to handle the message"* only then will you receive a valid response from the `sendMessage` request

The result from their example is `undefined`

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
   console.log(response.farewell);
});
<- undefined
```

If you are attempting to perform a HTTP request from within your chrome extension, you should use [XHR](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr)

```
var data = $.toJSON({'content': 'the paste content'});

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "http://myserver/data/add/", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-length", data.length);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
xhr.setRequestHeader('Remote-User', 'myuser');
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
      console.log('xhr response: '+ xhr.responseText);
  }
}
xhr.send(data);
```

Comment: You can also use [postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) for chrome to test REST services

Comment: Yeah, [XMLHttpReques](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) or the `$.ajax` with JQuery should do it for you

Comment: Updated my code with changes but still no luck though

Comment: Show me what you got

Comment: Sorry I updated my question with new code and the return is just same "undefined"

Comment: And when using XHR, remember to set the [allowed domains](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr.html) in the manifest. Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4838604/470560