# post data from chrome extension

Tags: javascript, curl, post, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I have a rest method to receive data from user, here is the `CURL` command:

**curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "data_test" http://localhost:8080/datum**

Now I'm trying to `POST` data, using java-script:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
let url='http://localhost:8080/datum';
let data=body;
request.open('POST', url, true);
request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.send(data);
```

But this receives nothing.

I'm using this java-script in a **Chrome-Extension**.

Comment: Modern Chrome doesn't allow content scripts to make cross-origin requests. Do it in your background script and use messaging to transfer the results, more info and examples in the [official CORB explainer](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/extension-content-script-fetches).

Comment: but this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35025424/10305444) says something else , i'm not sure what to do.. @wOxxOm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my current code :

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:8080/datum", true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
          }
        }
        xhr.send(dat);
```

It works, problem was in my rest api.